# iterate over vector of custom pair using 'std::algorithm' no explicit loops

Tags: c++, c++11

i wrote my own Pairs class:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
template<class K, class V>
class MyPair : public std::pair<K, V>
{
public:
    MyPair(){};
    MyPair(const K & x, const V & y) : std::pair<K, V>(x, y) {} 
    friend bool operator==(const MyPair& p1, const MyPair &p2)
    {
        return p1.first == p2.first; // requires that type K implements operator=
    }
    bool operator() (const MyPair& p1, const MyPair &p2)
    {
        return ( p1.first < p2.first ); // requires that type K implements operator<
    }
};
```

and i declared a vector of these custom pairs, and i am trying to use a std::for_each function to implement a print() function, but for some reason i can't do that, i am getting all kind of errors, i have a feeling that this might be duo to the need for a custom iterator ?
how would i implement a solution, without explicit loops?

```
typedef typename std::vector<MyPair<std::string, int> > myVecType;
myVecType wordvec;
void WordVector::print() const
{
    std::for_each(wordvec.begin(), wordvec.end(), [&](){});
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? btw I can see that the predicate takes no parameters when it needs to take a single parameter equal to the `value_type`.

Comment: i tried several lambda functions and each time i got different errors, i will update the post with errors if needed

Answer (score 1):

The predicate for a `std::for_each()` needs to take a parameter because this function passes each element every time it iterates:

```c++
std::for_each(wordvec.begin(), wordvec.end(),
    [&] (MyPair<std::string, int>& p) { /* ... */ });
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: And there is no good reason to specify `[&]` since there is no capture at all… With C++14 support: `[](auto &x) { … }`

Comment: i tried that without 'const', why do we need const here?,what should be done is i want to modify the pair's elements values?

Comment: @binaryA You specified your member function as const, though.